# will or be v-ing?

Tags: future, ing

This is one of the questions used in the ongoing national exam in my country. Although suggested answers have come out, I'd like to confirm the correct answer.

"The headmaster has decided that three lecture halls ___________ in our school."
A. will be built
B. are being built
C. will be building
D. will build

Comment: Not C or D as halls do not build

Comment: In theory, both A and B make grammatical sentences that make sense, though B sounds rather unusual (if they’re currently being built, they’re currently being built, regardless of what the headmaster decides). Then again, A sounds quite odd too—building new lecture halls is not usually something that a headmaster decides, but something a board of directors and a whole host of other people have to have a say in. C and D are grammatically correct, but make absolutely no sense whatsoever (buildings cannot build anything, people do that).

Comment: In terms of grammar both A. and B. would be permissible but only one really makes sense and that is A. In theory you could come up with a situation where there is some dispute as to how many lecture halls whatever is being built constitutes in which case B. might be possible.

Comment: @DRF You could also have a situation where the headmaster was a bit loony and in a Douglas Adamsesque style was wondering what that noise outside his office was. “After dismissing that it was a sabre-tooth tiger vomiting on the lawn or a mobile ice-cream parlour playing volleyball with a marble gargoyle, the headmaster finally decided that the noise was caused by three lecture halls being built in the school grounds” or something like that. Hardly a likely scenario, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Hardly likely but most enjoyable.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What Avon said.:)

Comment: My brother just took part in the exam. It appears that he's been taught to think this "are being built" is in the future tense, conveying the meaning that "something has been planned and is to be carried out". So he chose B and B is also the answer we found on the internet.

Comment: That's quite shocking to me Hugh. "are to be built" would convey that 'has been planned, will happen' meaning. 'are being built' should only mean construction has begun imo.

Comment: If you want future tense the usual structure would be either "will/shall be built" or possible "are going to be built". "are being built" tends to indicate currently ongoing building activity. Though I think there is  a slightly coloquial use in which "are being built" might be possible. Namely something along the lines of "This discussion has gone on long enough. I've decided three lecture halls are being built and that's that." but it grates.

Comment: What about expressions like "I’m seeing the dentist tomorrow." I'm not convinced by the answer given by some unknown folk from the Internet (I'm talking about the other answer I found on the internet, not yours; for all I know he's just another overconfident student who also took part in the exam), but I still have doubts that it might be THE answer.

Comment: I'm betting that most of you here either have great amount of experience in English, or are native, so your help would be more trustworthy.

Comment: We've had discussions on ELU before, if my memory is correct, about the intransitive usage of 'build' (and there are certainly internet examples, eg 'Stirling Bridge will build on Grand River' / 'and a new bridge will build on the original site.'). If allowed, D is certainly licensed, and probably C. It depends on which usage Czar you like best.

Comment: @Janus The middle usage for 'build' is not unknown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer here is A:

> The headmaster has decided that three lecture halls **will be built** in our school.

This is because the "has decided" part of the sentence indicates a decision prior to further action, so the rest of the sentence is a subordinate clause. As the buildings are the subject of the subordinate clause, you can only refer to them as complete because they aren't building themselves.

---

There seems to be some debate about the tense of answer B, "are being built" is the present progressive tense; something that is currently happening. For example, to extract the subordinate clause:

> "Three lecture halls **are being built** in our school."

As it's own sentence this makes perfect sense, but it means that the action is ongoing.

The important distinction is the decision of the Headmaster, and a perfect demonstration of why context is important. The second part of the sentence is dependent upon the first half, and while it makes sense by itself, it doesn't make sense in conjunction with the first half.

If you are relatively new to English (I'm a native English speaker, and grammar enthusiast) then you might read [this ELL page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8418/is-being-vs-has-been) and see if it helps.

Comment: Right. Answer B literally has the headmaster deciding that something is happening. But the thing happening—namely the fact that halls are being built—is at this point happening quite independently of the headmaster's "decision" that it is happening. In short, the decision that the headmaster is capable of making is to build in the future (hence, Answer A, "will be built," is correct), not to notice what's actually going on already (halls "are being built").